# VB.Net / ASP.Net Datatable not storing values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im working on an Asp.net / VB.net website and coming from a C# / WPF background things are still a little new to me.

I have declared a DataTable like so:

```
Public notificationList As DataTable
```

And I have then used the Page_Load event handler to populate it and bind it to a control on my page, which all works fine

```
 notificationList = dbGetNotificationsList(1)
     rptNotify.DataSource = notificationList
     rptNotify.DataBind()
```

However in another method i need to be able to access this DataTable, yet whenever I do it always appears as nothing. Do I need to be storing this value elsewhere like in the session etc?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't store the DataTable in Session, because every user would hold it's own instance, that is not very scaleable if number of users is increasing. Also the data might have changed since the last postback but you are still holding the old data. Hence, why don't you load the DataTable on every postback where you need it?

Comment: The data here contains a list of users and a value to indicate if a checkbox next to that users name should be checked. I want to use 2 way binding on the checkbox to store all the checked values in this DataTable then basically convert the DT to XML and pass it to a stored procedure to update my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the datatable in a Session or a persistent variable on the server side so that it can be accessed again when the page posts back. Plus, check whether your viewstate is turned on or off as this can sometimes cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. ASP.NET applications are stateless, it means that after every postback to the server all the data will be lost. So, it's up to you care about your data, wherever you want: session, viewstate, cache etc.